# Cakephp 3 : Without use joining is it possible load another model in a model?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

In controller I can use `loadModel` method to get another table data in cakephp.But is it possible in model? For example I have used ORM/Table class. I defined my table name used `table` method.Like below code

```
$this->table('blogs');
```

Is it possible declare another table in same way without association ?

Note : I am able to do it in controller.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? Having a model know about the outside world without using associations or dependeny injection, doesn't sound like an overly good idea to me.

Comment: I have two table attendance and users, I want to see all users data in attendance table, in attendance table I will add a selection field to add student present status. That's why I need users table data in attendance index.

Comment: Sounds like these table should be associated with each other, which again begs the question, why not? You've only described what you want to do, but not why there is a technical _need_ to do things without associations/joins! Also you may want to show some code, as it's hard to tell whether you are talking about reading, or saving, or...

Comment: @ndm I am actually talking about Loading Additional Models, Here I have a confuse. I don't know which one is best practices. For example I always follow this link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models , but I am thinking if I can load it in model if may data fetch time will be faster. I am not sure I am right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a model in another table you can use TableRegistry [Reference](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#using-the-tableregistry)

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry
$otherTable = TableRegistry::get('other');
//do something with the other table
//example
$someRecord = $otherTable->find()->first();
```

If your model is associated with the other model that you want to load via an association (belongsTo, hasOne etc.) then you can directly use it like this for example:

```
$this->otherModel->find()->contain()->where(['someCondition' => 'value'])->first()
```

Having said that, you really cannot define two tables into one if that is what you are trying to do. You can load and use a different table inside another table, but you can't define two tables under one table class.

I don't really understand why you don't want to define an association here as it sounds exactly like what you should do, but I hope the table registry option covers you